# Undefined variable in 'if' statement

Tags: matlab, variables, if-statement

I'm writing a script for an aerodynamics class and I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'dCt_dx'.
Error in Project2_Iteration (line 81)
Ct = trapz(x,dCt_dx)
```

I'm not sure what the cause is. It's something to do with my if statement. My script is below:

```
clear all
clc
global dr a n Vinf Vr w rho k x c cl dr B R beta t

%Environmental Parameters
n = 2400; %rpm
Vinf = 154; %KTAS
rho = 0.07647 * (.7429/.9450); %from mattingly for 8kft
a = 1084; %speed of sound, ft/s, 8000 ft
n = n/60; %convert to rps
w = 2*pi*n;
Vinf = (Vinf*6076.12)/3600; %convert from KTAS to ft/s
k = length(c);
dr = R/k; %length of each blade element

for i = 1:k
  r(i) = i*dr - (.5*dr); %radius at center of blade element
  dA = 2*pi*r*dr; %Planform area of blade element
  x(i) = r(i)/R;
  if x(i) > .15 && x(i-1) < .15
    i_15 = i;
  end
  if x(i) > .75 && x(i-1) < .75
    i_75h = i;
    i_75l = i-1;
  end
  Vr(i) = w*r(i) + Vinf;

  %Aerodynamic Parameters
  M = Vr(i)/a;
  if M > 0.9
    M = 0.9;
  end
  m0 = 0.9*(2*pi/(1-M^2)^0.5); %lift-curve slope (2pi/rad)

  %1: Calculate phi
  phi = atan(Vinf/(2*pi*n*r(i)));

  %2: Choose Vo
  Vo = .00175*Vinf;

  %3: Calculate Theta
  theta = atan((Vinf + Vo)/(2*pi*n*r(i)))-phi;

  %4:
  if option == 1
    %calculate cl(i) from c(i)
    sigma = (B*c(i))/(pi*R);
    if sigma > 0
      cl(i) = (8*x(i)*theta*cos(phi)*tan(phi+theta))/sigma;
    else
      cl(i) = 0;
    end
  else %option == 2
    %calculate c(i) from cl(i)
    if cl(i) ~= 0
      sigma = (8*x(i)*theta*cos(phi)*tan(phi+theta))/cl(i);
    else
      sigma = 0;
    end
    c(i) = (sigma*pi*R)/B;
    if c(i) < 0
      c(i) = 0;
    end
  end

  %5: Calculate cd
  cd(i) = 0.0090 + 0.0055*(cl(i)-0.1)^2;

  %6: calculate alpha
  alpha = cl(i)/m0;

  %7: calculate beta
  beta(i) = phi + alpha + theta;

  %8: calculate dCt/dx and dCq/dx
  phi0 = phi+theta;
  lambda_t = (1/(cos(phi)^2))*(cl(i)*cos(phi0) - cd(i)*sin(phi0));
  lambda_q = (1/(cos(phi)^2))*(cl(i)*sin(phi0) + cd(i)*cos(phi0));
  if x(i) >= 0.15
    dCt_dx(i) = ((pi^3)*(x(i)^2)*sigma*lambda_t)/8; %Roskam eq. 7.47, pg. 280
    dCq_dx(i) = ((pi^3)*(x(i)^3)*sigma*lambda_q)/16; %Roskam eq. 7.48, pg 280
  else
    dCt_dx(i) = 0;
    dCq_dx(i) = 0;
  end

  %calculate Mdd
  t(i) = (0.04/(x(i)^1.2))*c(i);
  Mdd(i) = 0.94 - (t(i)/c(i)) - cl(i)/10;
end

%9: calculate Ct, Cq, Cd
Ct = trapz(x,dCt_dx)
Cq = trapz(x,dCq_dx)
D = 2*R;
Q=(rho*(n^2)*(D^5)*Cq)
T=(rho*(n^2)*(D^4)*Ct)
```

Comment: You can set breakpoints in your code by clicking the dashes next to the line numbers (a red circle should appear). After you run your code, it will stop at the breakpoint and you can step through line-by-line by pressing `F10`. You can examine the value of variables as they change this way. If you still can't figure out the problem, come back and let us know.

Comment: I can't seem to have any success. The red dot just disappears when I run the script and I receive the same error (even when the break is above where the error is happeneing)

Comment: I would like to add that except that you did not get a crash at `dr=R/K` in the beginning (which probably has to do with globals getting initialized to 0). I think that you really abuses globals here. For the first, these variables are not required to be global ( I would say globals are normally unnecessary in matlab, but it can simplify GUI sometimes). Second, the way you definite them: If you want to use globals. At least place them in a struct. The way you use them now gives you no control over the code. Also, globals in matlab is not the same as globals in c, so you should read up on them.

Answer (score 0):

When I step through your script, I see that the the entire `for i = 1:k` loop is skipped because `k=0`. You set `k = length(c)`, but `c` was never initialized to a value, so it has length zero.

Because of this, `dCt_dx` is never given a value--and more importantly the majority of your script is never run.

If you're going to be using MATLAB in the future, I really suggest learning how to do this. It makes it a lot easier to find bugs. Try looking at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdNY9n8lV1Y).